# Validate at least One check box is checked in django html template via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am showing pagination gird on django templates,

```
{% for result in page.object_list %}
<tr>
<td style="border:0;border-bottom:1px solid #eeeeee;">
<input type="checkbox" id="{{result.object.user_id}}" name="selectedvalues[]" value="{{ result.object.user_id }}">
            </td>
<td>.....</td>
<tr>
{% endfor %}
```

and there is a button at the end of this to delete the users. I want to validate that on delete button press it should validate that at least one user is selected via check box.

```
$("#delete").click(function(){
    var $checkboxes $('# td input[type="checkbox"]');
    $('.checkbox input').each(function(index) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            break;
        } else {
            $(this).attr('value', 'False');
        }
      alert('You must select at lease one user');
    });

    });
```

but it is not working.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#delete").click(function() {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
        alert("Checked");
    } else {
        alert("Not checked");
    }
});
```

If you have other checkboxes on page then add a `class` to your `<input>` and select items in JS by this class:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="deletechk" name="selectedvalues[]"
                                         value="{{ result.object.user_id }}">
```

And in Javascript code:

```
if ($('.deletechk:checked').length > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your Javascript to below and instead of alerts can set a flag and break loop by returning false if they have checked a checkbox (see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uet15230/)):

```
$("#delete").click(function(){
    var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $(checkboxes).each(function(index) {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('checked');
        } else {            
            alert('You must select at lease one user');
        }      
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML add :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{result.object.user_id}}"       
name="selectedvalues[]" value="{{ result.object.user_id }} class="mybox">
```

jquery:

```
$( "#delete" ).click(function(e) {
var checks=( $(".mybox").val());
if(!checks)
{
  alert('You must select at lease one user');
  e.PreventDefault()
{



});
```